# User's profile is not creating

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am tried to register user Today BUT it shows

> AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'encode'

This was working before few days but when i tried today then it is keep showing.
When i `python manage.py createsuperuser` in terminal then same error is showing.

Full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\app\users\views.py", line 10, in signup_view
    user = form.save()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 131, in save
    user.save()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 727, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 776, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 182, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 182, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "D:\app\mains\models.py", line 264, in post_save_create_profile
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 727, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 765, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1415, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1360, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1360, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1359, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1310, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\autoslug\fields.py", line 276, in pre_save
    slug = self.slugify(value)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\autoslug\utils.py", line 34, in slugify
    return django_slugify(unidecode(value))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\unidecode\__init__.py", line 48, in unidecode_expect_ascii
    bytestring = string.encode('ASCII')
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

users/views.py

```
def signup_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('mains:home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60,default='')
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def post_save_create_pro(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    username = forms.CharField(help_text=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (         
            'username',
        )
```

In error in browser it is showing this with `form.save()` highlighted.

[image]

When i click on register then this error is raising . When i check in admin then user is created BUT profile is not created, BUT it should show me User has no object Profile BUT it is showing something different.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: *profile is not created* - because you are  **creating but not saving the instance**  in your ```post_save``` signal.

Comment: Please see @Jafoor answer. That is what I was talking about.

Comment: Why are you using a ```default``` value for a ```OneToOneField``` ? It doesn't make sense to me. I am taking about this ```user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)```

Comment: That is not a DB issue. There is problem with your code. Are you using any encoding in your code ?

Comment: @Ram [`objects.create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.create) will actually create the object in the database

Comment: @PrOgRaMmEr Based on the traceback it seems you are using `django-autoslug`. Can you show where you are using it? You also said it was working a few days back. Did you update this library in the past few days? The library is expecting a string but is getting a `User` instance.

Comment: @bdbd, It is working after changing virtual environment. I created a new virtual environment and It worked. AND i also successfully installed `django-autoslug`

Comment: That's great! Curious what happened to the old virtual env.. Maybe compare if the old and new virtual envs have the same version for this library

Comment: @bdbd, I don't even  know yet what was the problem. BUT i think (not sure) the problem was in the `middleware` because i think i was adding a middleware of a library which was not installed in `env`

Comment: @bdbd, Yes the versions was same.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating profile but not saving it. Try it.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60,default='')
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def post_save_create_pro(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a **New Virtual Environment** and It Worked.

**What was the Problem :-**

```
Not 100 % Sure BUT i think i was adding a middleware of a library which was 
not installed in virtual environment
```